# who could tell me that the following code was encoding with which encoding system?

Tags: python-cryptography

who could tell me that the following code was encoding with which encoding system?

Is Base 64 part of cryptography ? 
How i can decrypt the code please help me .

sorry for my english

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
import urllib2
import re
import os
import xbmcplugin
import xbmcgui
import xbmcaddon
import xbmcvfs
import traceback
import cookielib , base64 , requests
import errno
from socket import error as socket_error
import socket
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup , BeautifulSoup , BeautifulSOAP
oo000 = 500
try :
 from xml . sax . saxutils import escape
except : traceback . print_exc ( )
try :
 import json
except :
 import simplejson as json /// 
import time
ii = False
oOOo = [ 'plugin.video.dramasonline' , 'plugin.video.f4mTester' , 'plugin.video.shahidmbcnet' , 'plugin.video.SportsDevil' , 'plugin.stream.vaughnlive.tv' , 'plugin.video.ZemTV-shani' ]
if 59 - 59: Oo0Ooo . OO0OO0O0O0 * iiiIIii1IIi . iII111iiiii11 % I1IiiI
if 27 - 27: iIiiiI1IiI1I1 * IIiIiII11i *IiIIi1I1Iiii  - Ooo00oOo00o
class I1IiI ( urllib2 . HTTPErrorProcessor ) :
 def http_response ( self , request , response ) :
  return response
```

Comment: Google might help you here, though it is unclear what the question is. What code?

Comment: dear  the is in phyton

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How i can decrypt this code

Comment: I think we may be using words differently. Do you mean to ask "how does this python code work"? Because I see nothing here to decrypt. It's obtuse, nearly obfuscated, code, to be sure. But one almost expects that from terse Python. My advice is to... learn to read Python.

Comment: yes i want to understand how how does this python code work  ,i want to decode this code

Comment: The code is obfuscated in some manner. It is perhaps a PYC file from the built-in bytecode tool. Google will help here.

Comment: A short Google search suggests this is decompiled Python code recreated from Python bytecode. I suggest searching on "PYC" and seeing where that leads you. This code is incomplete, though. There are parts missing for full understanding, or it did not decompile cleanly.

Comment: thanks you , you can see the complet code  her :[default.zip](https://github.com/Kodi-vStream/venom-xbmc-addons/files/1117334/default.zip)   you  decompile with What software ?

Comment: and her  you can see all fill the kodi addon :[repository.persia-1.0.4.zip](https://github.com/Kodi-vStream/venom-xbmc-addons/files/1117342/repository.persia-1.0.4.zip)

Comment: A web search on "python decompiling" and "python bytecode" is a good start.

Comment: the code is protected by pyobfuscate  methode , and i cant find more information for decompiling for this methode ..